# antlr match parser rule instead of token

Tags: antlr

I'm trying to match the following sequences:

`var1.x , "cssStyleName : styleValue";`

cssStyleName and styleValue are ... well...  css compliant styles, e.g. `color: #000 !important; *width: 99.94680851063829%;"` etc.

```
inputSpecs: modelVariable (COMMA  cssStyle )*;

modelVariable: TEXT ('.' childVar)*;

childVar : TEXT; 

cssStyle:  styleName COLON styleValue+ SEMICOLON;

styleName : ASTERISK? TEXT ;

styleValue :  TEXT | STYLE_VALUE;



COLON: ':';
SEMICOLON: ';';
ASTERISK: '*';
COMMA: ',';
TEXT : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'| '_' | '-' | '0'..'9')+ ;
STYLE_VALUE: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'| '_' | '-' | '0'..'9' | '%' |'#' |'.')+ '!important'?;
```

The problem lies in declaring the `'.'` at the end of the STYLE_VALUE token. When I declare it, I get *NoViableAltException* right after parsing *var1.x*, probably due to the fact that *modelVariable* is matched as a STYLE_VALUE and not as a TEXT.

How can I have a subset of TEXT (STYLE_VALUE) be matched as *STYLE_VALUE* and *'.' TEXT* to be matched as TEXT with a dot in front of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the lexer to treat `var1.x` as 3 separate tokens (`var1`, `.`, and `x`), then you need to make sure that *no* lexer rule can include the `.` with either of the two other tokens. As a start, you'll need to remove the `STYLE_VALUE` lexer rule. You'll also want to create the following lexer rule, and `'.'` should not appear in any other lexer rule.

```
DOT : '.';
```

Instead of handling the syntax of the style value in the lexer, you'll need to handle it in the parser to ensure that `DOT` is always treated properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer 280z28 . I can understand ANTLR is forcing me to be very specific in my tokens declaration, but it would have been simpler if ANTLR would just listen to the parser declarations. I solved the problem by replacing: `styleValue :  HASH? TEXT (DOT TEXT)* (PERCENT)* PRIORITY?;`. The downside of this is that now I have to include in my styleValue rule every possible CSS value character. Isn't there a way to match *everything between : and ;* ?